# Prevent other Methods from running under a condition is met in a previous Method

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

My problem is when the user clicks on myButton the program operates perfectly fine. But if the user was to input a value less than 3 in the first textbox a message box will appear to the user stating that the value must be greater than 3 metres. If you click OK the next method in myButton runs anyway and the result message box appears anyway.

I've tried looking around to solve this problem of mine using Nested For Loops but failed to get them to work (most likely a fault on my end). I also prefer not to use Goto because it isn't exactly good programming practice to use. Of course you can tell me otherwise if you want :) .

```
// Button
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkIfNumericalValue();
            testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet();
            testIfTextBoxTwosMinimumIsMet();
            displayResultToUser();
            resetOrClose();
        }

// Textbox One
public void testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet() 
        {
            if (length < 3) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("length must be greater than 3 metres");
            }
        }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated this is also my second attempt at C# on Visual Studio 2012. Do not worry this has nothing to do with my year 10 schooling as my school doesn't have a programming subject. This problem occurs in testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet() and testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet() as well but if someone can help me with this one method I should be able to fix the rest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `throw` an `exception` from your inner functions and catch it from your button's function, something like this:

```
// Button
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        checkIfNumericalValue();
        testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet();
        testIfTextBoxTwosMinimumIsMet();
        displayResultToUser();
        resetOrClose();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
        // The error message we defined at the exception we threw
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

// Textbox One
public void testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet() 
{
    if (length < 3) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Length must be greater than 3 meters.");
    }
}
```

---

An alternative would be to deal with the validation within your button like so:

```
// Button
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkIfNumericalValue();
    if (length < 3) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Length must be greater than 3 meters.");
        return;
    }
    testIfTextBoxTwosMinimumIsMet();
    displayResultToUser();
    resetOrClose();
}
```

What happens above is that the **`return`** will leave that function without further processing anything else.

Comment: As simple as it seems :P The return; to leave the function and not continue processing any further was very helpful. Thank you for those two examples :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need some other variable to track whether or not you have encountered errors. To do this, you could have a `bool noErrors` variable defined, and you should return a boolean from your error check methods that is `True` if there were no errors, otherwise `False`. This way you know if you ran into any problems.

Finally, you should check for the state of `errrorsFound` before running any of your other methods.

For example:

```
// Button
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool noErrors = 
        isNumericalValue() &&
        textBoxOnesMinimumIsMet() &&
        textBoxTwosMinimumIsMet();

    if (noErrors)
    {
        displayResultToUser();
        resetOrClose();  // I'm not sure if this should happen regardless of errors?
    }        
}

// Textbox One
public bool textBoxOnesMinimumIsMet() 
{
    if (length < 3) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("length must be greater than 3 metres");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: isNumericalValue is a Private Bool so I unfortunately can't use && operators :(

Comment: @AsDf you mean private void? because if its private bool than it would be usable yes.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I'm understanding this correctly, if the text boxes contain numerical values, text box 1 meets the minimum and text box 2 meets the minimum, you want to displayResultToUser() and then resetOrClose().

If that's the case, you can have the 3 methods checkIfNumericalValue(), testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet() and testIfTextBoxTwosMinimumIsMet() return a bool depending on what the minimum condition is and then write something like this:

```
private void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkIfNumericalValue() && testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet(Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxOne.Text)) && testIfTextBoxTwosMinimumIsMet(Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxTwo.Text)))
    {
        displayResultToUser();
        resetOrClose();
    }
}

public bool testIfTextBoxOnesMinimumIsMet(int length)
{
    if (length < 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("length must be greater than 3 metres");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```